# Question 2.1 of Bartle's Elements of Integration

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, integration

The problem 2.1 of Bartle's Elements of Integration says:

> Give an exemple of a function $f$ on $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is not
>   $\boldsymbol{X}$-mensurable, but is such that the function $|f|$ and
>   $f^2$ are $\boldsymbol{X}$-mensurable.

But, if one define $f^{+}:= \max\{f(x), 0\}$ e $f^{-}\max\{-f(x),0\}$, then $f = f^{+} - f^{-}$ and $|f| = f^{+}+f^{-}$. Also, $f$ is $\boldsymbol{X}$-mensurable iff $f^{+}$ and $f^{-}$ are mensurable. Therefore, $|f|$ is mensurable iff $f$ is mensurable. Is the problem wrong?

Edit:

Here $X$ is a set and $\boldsymbol{X}$ a $\sigma$-algebra over $X$.

Comment: I always thought the word mensurable was a funny word. Reading this question made me pick up good old Folland for a moment, where I see that it must have irked him too as he uses measurable as well. Go figure.

Comment: @mixedmath In Bartle's *The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure* he uses "measurable" too.  Odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any non-empty measurable set $U$ in $X$, and any non-empty non-measurable set $V$ in $U$. Let $f$ be the function that sends $U$ to $1$, except for the points in $V$, which are sent to $-1$. In other words, $f(x) = 1_{U\backslash V} - 1_V$.

Now $|f| =f^2 = 1_U$.

I see now that Bunder has written a similar idea (that I don't think is fleshed out yet as I see it so far).

**EDIT** (to match the edited question)

You ask:

> But, if one define $f^+:=\max\{f(x),0\}$ and $f^−= \max\{−f(x),0\}$, then $f=f^+−f^−$ and $|f|=f^++f^−$. Also, $f$ is $X$-mensurable iff $f^+$ and $f^−$ are mensurable. Therefore, $|f|$ is mensurable iff $f$ is mensurable. Is the problem wrong?

What makes you think that $f$ is measurable iff $f^+$ and $f^-$ are measurable? In my example above, $f^+ = 1_{U\backslash V}$ and $f^- = 1_V$, neither of which are measurable. This is clear for $1_V$. To see that $f^+$ here is not measurable, note that if it were measurable, then $1 - f^+ = 1_V$ would be measurable. But their sum is $1_U$, which is trivially measurable.

In other words, it is **not true** that $f$ measurable iff $f^+, f^-$ measurable.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I've ran across it and I was wondering if you could please explain why $1_{V}$ is not a measurable function if $V$ is a measurable set? (this is the same question as mark leeds posted in the comment to the other answer, and, to be honest, I also did not understand, in that answer, why $|1_{B}| = 1^2_{B}$ equals $1$...)

Comment: Indeed, you're right! I meant to specify that V should be nonmeasurable. I suppose others recognized the underlying idea? I don't know, but I've edited the answer.

Comment: No, it is **true** that $f$ is measurable iff $f^+$ and $f^-$ are measurable. The problem wants an example of a function that is **not mensurable**, so if $f$ is a function that is not measurable then $f^+$ **or** $f^-$ are not measurable. You gave an example of a function $f$ that is not measurable, so it is to expected that $f^+$ or $f^-$ are not measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Take any non-measurable set of $X$, say B. So $1_B$ will not be measurable but $1 = | 1_B | = 1_B^2$ are.

Comment: @mixedmath: could you explain in detail why $1_{V}$ is not measurable. Thanks.